# Converting int to int64, int variable still returning negative at int.MaxValue

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display the price of an item.  The price is multiplied by the item quantity.

```
int itemCost = itemPrice * itemQuanity;
```

When the quantity of the item becomes too much, the itemCost goes into negatives, meaning I need a larger int, so I changed the int to use int64.

```
int64 itemCost = itemPrice * itemQuantity;
```

With this change it still outputs a negative itemCost, what am I doing wrong?

I tried using

```
System.Convert.ToInt64(int value);
```

but that doesn't seem to work either, still getting a negative number when reaching int.MaxValue.

Comment: [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, one need to force "checked" to get the exception - see [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw(v=vs.110).aspx) - "By default, these non-constant expressions are not checked for overflow at run time either"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What types are `itemPrice` and `itemQuantity`?  If they're both `int`, you're going to get an `int` (32-bit) as an answer from the multiplication, which you're then storing in an `int64`.  At that point, the conversion (and overflow) has already happened, and casting to an `int64` won't help.

You need to ensure both operands are int64 *before* you multiply.  So if they aren't already,

```
int64 itemCost = ((int64) itemPrice) * ((int64) itemQuantity);
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try:

```
long itemCost = (long)itemPrice * (long)itemQuantity;
```

What happened is that you still tried to multiply two `int`, even if you stored the result in a `long`. Cast them to `long` first.

Answer (score 5):

Your second line of code is computing the product of `itemPrice * itemQuantity` **as Int32 values** and *then* converting that result to an Int64.  You need to convert the values to `long` *before* doing the multiplication.

```
long itemCost = itemPrice * (long) itemQuantity;
```